# Material-UI V0.20.2 and React 16.8.3 Autocomplete, enter event does not get triggered to confirm selection

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have the following component:

```
 <AutoComplete
    fullWidth
    errorText={dirty ? error : null}
    onNewRequest={value => onChange(countryCodesByName[value])}
    onUpdateInput={value => onChange(countryCodesByName.hasOwnProperty(value) ? countryCodesByName[value] : value)}
    searchText={countries[value] || value}
    {...inputProps}
    {...custom}
    menuStyle={{ overflowY: 'auto' }}
  />
```

My problem is, when searching for a country and I press enter to confirm the selection in the drop-down, the enter event is not triggered. The up and down arrows are working to navigate the list of countries but enter not.
With react 15 it worked because I had `react-tap-event-plugin`, but is deprecated:

```
React 16.4 removes a lot of internals (#121) this plugin depends on and will break the plugin.

Since the problem it solves has been fixed in most browsers by now you should migrate away from this plugin.
```

Comment: Material-ui v0.20.2 is deprecated as well. So, if you are upgrading react, then upgrade materail-ui as well.

Answer (score 0):

Update the version of you material ui on version: **v3.9.2**
https://material-ui.com/versions/

Comment: An update on that version for the all app, from version 0.20 will take a lot of time, this is not the desired solution. I am looking for a solution with the current version.

Comment: Any solution using the current version will probably take more time than updating.

Comment: If react 16.8 don't work with Material-ui v0.20.2 there are no way ... you have to update...so or update material UI or came-back to old version of react